# Barcode encoding in XSLT

Tags: xslt, barcode

We are looking for a solution to encode a barcode in XSLT.  I cannot find anything about how to only encode this in XSLT.  I'm not an expert in XSLT,  I have been looking in this issue for about 2 weeks and that's all my experience I have in XSLT.

I tried the JSBarcode but that script also want to display the barcode, but the barcode itself needs to be rendered by another system.

I'm not sure if this is even possible to accomplish.

Comment: Did you search this site for "barcode XSLT"? How is your problem different from those that you find when you do this search?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to take a look at [http://www.renderx.com/~renderx/Demos/barcode/index.html](http://www.renderx.com/%7Erenderx/Demos/barcode/index.html)

The provided stylesheets takes a XML-Documents and converts a series of digits to a barcode. If you don't want to start with a XML-Document, you may store your data inside a variable inside the XSLT-script.